# With MtGox gone, how can I know the current price of a bitcoin?

Tags: exchange-rate

Firstly, I acknowledge that there is no official bitcoin price and it is market determined, but I have seen various websites quote the current price of bitcoin and so on.

In the past my bitcoin wallet told me the price of a coin making reference to MtGox's index.

Now that MtGox is gone, what are the most reliable resources to obtain both present and past bitcoin prices?

Or are there some credible exchanges that I can use as a reference to compare less credible sellers with?

Comment: http://bitcoincharts.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the most accurate is the [coindesk bitcoin price index](http://www.coindesk.com/price/).
It is a mean volume weighted between major exchanges.

UPDATE:
It isn't volume weighted, it's a simple average. For more information read [source](http://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin-price-index/)